# Python 3.0 - Idle wont open. It just bounces in the dock

Tags: python, macos

Python/Unix noob. On Mac OSX.

Been running Python 2.7.2 for a few weeks, along with Idle app. No problems.

Today I just installed Python3.0 along side 2.7 - tested both and can still be ran via Terminal.

Now when I open Idle for 2.7, it opens just fine. But when I open the new Idle app within the Python3.0 folder, the app just bounces in the doc and never opens.

The error from Console is as follows:

```
12/2/11 11:57:13.612 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: 
([0x0-0x38038].org.python.IDLE[313]) 
posix_spawn("/Applications/Python-3.0/Mac/IDLE/IDLE.app/Contents/MacOS/IDLE", ...): 
No such file or directory
```

How do I get Idle to open for Python3.0?

Comment: What is the installation path of Python3, and how does IDLE reference it? There might be an incorrect path in the first line of the main `IDLE` file (assuming that IDLE is written in python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use Python 3.0.  The initial releases of Python 3 were somewhat experimental and had a number of serious problems that have been fixed in subsequent releases.  The fixed problems include the one you're seeing which I believe was covered by [Issue5196](http://bugs.python.org/issue5196). The current release of Python 3 is 3.2.2 and is considered production-ready.  You can find installers for Mac OS X [here](http://www.python.org/download/).  There are two installers depending on which version of OS X you are running.   If on OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) or 10.7 (Lion), pay particular attention to the cautions [here](http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) about also installing the current version of ActiveState Tcl/Tk to be used instead of the buggy Tcl/Tk 8.5 shipped by Apple in those systems.