# Mac OS X: _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: python, macos, macports

As I said, I have installed Python 3.3 from Macports.

Now when I do a spotlight search for Idle

```
Idle -- Python 3.3
```

shows up. However when I try to click it, nothing happens. No error is shown or anything- it plain does not start.

What do you think might be wrong?

It is reminiscent of this question: [Python 3.0 - Idle wont open. It just bounces in the dock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8366401/python-3-0-idle-wont-open-it-just-bounces-in-the-dock)

The difference is that I get no error messages and am using 3.3

---

Update:

Now I tried setting Py3.3 as my main version using macports select. Then I tried opening IDLE from the console and got the following error message:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/bin/idle", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1421, in main
    root = Tk(className="Idle")
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1756, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

Comment: Is there anything written in the console log? (Search for Console.app)

Comment: I tried running it from the console instead and got the error added above. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using macports, install `py33-tkinter`

`sudo port install py33-tkinter`

Edit: Make sure you have X11 or Xquartz installed too.

Comment: Followed your instructions exactly, no change. Even tried restarting. When adding tkinter to my googling I found this though: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58921/python-idle-from-macports-cant-start so now I think I have some clue as to what is wrong.

Comment: Have you got X11 or Xquartz installed? Installing py33-tkinter solved the problem for me :/

Comment: Most likely, as I have used IDLE succesfully before, with my nonmacport IDLE versions. Don't delete your answer though, I'm sure it will work for some others with the same problem.

Comment: Not all versions of IDLE require X11 or Xquartz but the macports version does. You can look for it using Spotlight. If it's not installed you can download it from http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/.

Comment: Worked, but looks much worse than the vanilla IDLE though- but that is not your fault, just a general complaint. (Will upvote tomorrow-vote limit reached)

Comment: I have the same problem when using cygwin on windows. I installed perl-Tk, from apt-cyg, but nothing changed :(

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with python32 port on my OS X Lion 10.7.5 and got fixed simply by installing py32-tkinter port. I checked and already has installed X11. Thanks.