# How to define a global array in python

Tags: python, arrays, plot

How to define a global array in python
I want to define tm and prs as global array, and use them in two functions, how could I define them?

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tm = []  
prs = []

def drw_prs_tm(msg):
    tm = np.append(tm,t)
    prs = np.append(prs,s)

def print_end(msg):
    plt.plot(tm,prs,'k-')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Comment: You can also try importing `__builtin__` module and add them to it: `__builtin__.tm = []`

Comment: @Milo: But that would be a terrible thing to do!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to refer them as `global <var_name>` in the method

```
def drw_prs_tm(msg):
    global tm
    global prs

    tm = np.append(tm,t)
    prs = np.append(prs,s)

def print_end(msg):
    global tm
    global prs
    plt.plot(tm,prs,'k-')
```

Read more on `global` [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) and [here](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)

> The global statement is a declaration which holds for the entire current code block. It means that the listed identifiers are to be interpreted as globals. It would be impossible to assign to a global variable without global, although free variables may refer to globals without being declared global.
>
> In Python, variables that are only referenced inside a function are implicitly global. If a variable is assigned a new value anywhere within the function’s body, it’s assumed to be a local. If a variable is ever assigned a new value inside the function, the variable is implicitly local, and you need to explicitly declare it as ‘global’.

Comment: Its important to add that you only need the `global` prefix if you want to assign a new value to the variable.  If you just want to read the value, you can just use its regular name.

Comment: @TylerAndFriends: "change the value" is less clear than "assigned a new value".

Comment: thanks!but it is really weird that I can have the array of tm and prs which both of them have the same number of element, when I use plt.plot(tm,prs,'k-'), it return with error:

Comment: _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Comment: would [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286324/mac-os-x-tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variabl) help?

Answer (score 0):

With the [`global`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.4/ref/global.html) keyword:

```
def drw_prs_tm(msg):
    global tm, prs    # Make tm and prs global
    tm = np.append(tm,t)
    prs = np.append(prs,s)
```

Also, if you keep it as it currently is, then you do not need to declare `tm` and `prs` as global in the second function.  Only the first requires it because it is modifying the global lists.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have function inside of other function use this:

```
def ex8():
    ex8.var = 'foo'
    def inner():
        ex8.var = 'bar'
        print 'inside inner, ex8.var is ', ex8.var
    inner()
    print 'inside outer function, ex8.var is ', ex8.var
ex8()

inside inner, ex8.var is  bar
inside outer function, ex8.var is  bar
```

More: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/python-variable-scope-notes/