# no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I want to teach Python for kids. I want them to use Jupyter Notebook. To avoid the hassle of installation, I want them to use a free online Jupyter Notebook. I thought google's colab ([link](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks)) and jupyter.org ([link](https://jupyter.org/try)) could be best solutions. However, I tried them both and got the error message below:

```
from turtle import *
colors = ['red', 'purple', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange']
for x in range(360):
  pencolor(colors[x % 6])
  width(x / 100 + 1)
  forward(x)
  left(59)
```

> TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at this issue:

[ipython notebook - $DISPLAY variable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854276/ipython-notebook-display-variable-error)

Your problem might be solved if you run before:

```
%matplotlib inline
```