# Tried to execute the easygui module in google colab but received no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

Tags: google-colaboratory, easygui

Links where I found solutions but don't understand:

- [no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56694317/no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variable-in-jupyter-notebook)
- [ipython notebook - $DISPLAY variable error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26854276/ipython-notebook-display-variable-error)
- [ipython notebook on linux VM running matplotlib interactive with nbagg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26901890/ipython-notebook-on-linux-vm-running-matplotlib-interactive-with-nbagg)

**1. Summarize the problem**
Want to study python with my son, we have book called Hello World Computer Programming for kids and other beginners. In chapter 6 we move toward `create message boxes, button boxes, and choice boxes which will need to build our private app together`.

**2. Describe what you’ve tried**
I looked at previous questions and learned that in order to import the module, I would have to first move the easygui.py file into my google drive. Then I learn to use `[!pip install easygui]` to install the module, which also worked. I was able to import the module without any problem but once the system reads the line of code to create the msg box it crashes and returns the message.

> TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

I am completely clueless. I saw two similar situations but I'm new and I'm not sure how they solved this problem, they only listed that they used:

Your problem might be solved if you run before:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

My question is how and where did they do this because when i place this code before my only two lines a code i still get an error.

**3. When appropriate, show some code**

```
!pip install easygui
import easygui
easygui.msgbox("Hello There!")
```

and also with

```
%matplotlib inline
import easygui
easygui.msgbox("Hello There!")
```

[image: image of code and error]

Answer (score 1):

easygui runs on local machine. So it's working when you write your lines in an editor, for example Python IDE or Sublime Text etc.

google-colab is an online platform, which is different from local (machine) environment. That's why on colab, it doesn't perform the pop-up.