# IDLE refuses to launch in terminal. What should I do?

Tags: python-2.7

I am attempting to open IDLE from my terminal, but am constantly faced with this error:

```
File "/opt/local/bin/idle", line 5, in <module>
main()
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1553, in main
root = Tk(className="Idle")
File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1820, in __init__
self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

What does this error mean and how do I remedy it? I've tried reinstalling python, and installing the latest version of X11. I've also tried installing py27-tkinter (as suggested by answers to similar questions) but still with no luck. I am new to Python and would appreciate any suggestions that anyone can offer! I am using a Mac and Python 2.7.13.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at this answer?

[Mac OS X: _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286324/mac-os-x-tkinter-tclerror-no-display-name-and-no-display-environment-variabl)

It is very similar to your situation. Since you have already reinstalled a lot of your components, you should be familiar with these steps.

Try it in this way (taken from the link above):

> Using macports, install py33-tkinter
>
> sudo port install py33-tkinter
>
> Edit: Make sure you have X11 or Xquartz installed too.

You just need to replace py33-tkinter with your version of Python instead, which is probably `py27-tkinter`

EDIT:

Take a look at your current value of the environment variable. Use `echo $DISPLAY`. If its not set, can you try setting your environment variable as the error suggests?
Using `export DISPLAY=:0.0`

Comment: Yes, I have looked at that! And I've carried out those steps, but the error remains.

Comment: I tried that but the error becomes: _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0.0"

Comment: So then, I am going to assume that the error does in fact have something to do with the environment variable DISPLAY. Can you try setting DISPLAY to `127.0.0.1:8080` like this `export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:8080`?

Also, are you running this in a virtual environment?

Comment: The error still comes up as "_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "127.0.0.1:8080". What do you mean by virtual environment?

Comment: A virtual environment lets you setup various instances with different configurations (OS and stuff), on one machine by virtually allocating your host's resources to the machine. So I'm assuming you are not running it in a virtual environment, and simply running it on your local machine. 

Can you post the command you are using to try to open IDLE from the terminal? Also, have you opened it like that before?

Comment: Yes, I'm just running it on my local machine. I have opened it like that before, but recently I installed HORTON, so maybe that's interfered with it? I used to simply type "idle" in a terminal window, and it would launch it and open the python shell.

Comment: By Horton, do you mean the HortonWorks Sandbox? Yes, It may have intefered with your python configuration. Maybe you could try this as well: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38294/error-when-attempting-to-create-python-gui-using-tkinter-no-display-name-and-n , after the export, do `'xhost +' . What it does: https://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/xhost.1.html .

Comment: Thanks for all your help so far! No, that's not what I mean. Here's the link for the procedure I followed to install the program: https://theochem.github.io/horton/2.0.1/user_download_and_install_mac.html. Also, sadly, I've already reviewed that link and the command "xhost +" does not work...

Comment: Sure no problem. Can you clarify on the "Horton" you are talking about, maybe with a link or something?

Comment: This IS the link: https://theochem.github.io/horton/2.0.1/user_download_and_install_mac.html. Is this not clarification enough?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see that. One moment. Did you follow the guide on installation thoroughly? Especially the `1.2.5.3. Runtime configuration` part?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Did it give any errors during the course of the installation? Anything related to the environment variables? Because otherwise I suggest you uninstall Horton and see if it works (if thats possible). Then once again reinstall it, this time being sure of the steps.